# Did Ultear know there was a different way to defeat master Hades?

Tags: fairy-tail

In episode 116 after Ultear lost the fight with Gray, she tells him that he cannot beat Hades, but does not tell him anything about Hades' weakness (eg: his heart).

[image: Ultear telling Gray there is no other way]

This seems weird since when she had Zeref a couple episodes back, she was about to stab Hades in the back and take Zeref for her own purposes. This would imply that she was no longer on Hades' side.

Later we see that the guards knew that the room Hades' was in was something they could not lose control of.

[image: Lilly versus guards]

Since the guards knew about this wouldn't Ultear know this as too, seeing as she was pretty much raised by Hades?

Answer (score 4):

Urtear did know for sure. She had been trying to deceive Gray all along. She told Gray that the Iced Shell was the only way because the spell traps the caster as a shell of ice for all eternity. She wanted him to die because she thought Gray was the one responsible for her mother not loving her which was not true at all.

Urtear knew more about Hades than any of the outsiders. She obviously had a plan to kill Hades herself but having Gray kill him would be killing two birds with a single stone.

But Gray realizes that after he over hears her and sees her trying to kill Juvia.

Comment: I disagree, this takes place after the whole flashback from Ultear. In that flashback Ultear sees what actually happened. Her mother Ul was lied to about Ultear's dead. Because of this she took in the two pupils, Gray and Lyon. After this flashback Ultear doesn't seem to have any hard feelings with Gray. She even saves him in a later episode in the Eclipse arc.

Comment: Damn it you spoiled it for me.
And Yes that is indeed true. What I wrote was before the flashbacks of course when she was trying to trick Gray into using the iced shell in Hades. 
Oh and thanks for the spoiler -_-

Comment: Well sorry, I don't know why you would answer in the first place if you aren't cached up with the source material...

Comment: Dude did you even read the question? It's whether Urtear knew if there was a different way to defeat Hades other than using the Iced Shell. Where does the flashback or her saving Gray later in the series come in?

Comment: First off, its my own question so yes I know what i'm asking. Secondly take a look at [this](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/spoilers-in-comments) if you are worried about spoilers in comments. The flashback takes place a couple minutes before the first screenshot. And its Ultear instead of Urtear.

Comment: Then just tell me this.
The question was whether Ultear knew if there was a way to defeat her wasn't it? I don't get why you keep bringing the flashback in. I know that's where she realized what had happened but how is that related to the question?

Comment: Your answer isn't completely wrong, but I keep bringing this up because it seems odd that she did not tell Gray about this after setting aside the hard feelings she had.

Comment: Oh now I see what you're getting at. Well we can only speculate. Might be because she thought Gray had already seen through her facade back when he overheard and when she was about to kill Juvia.

Comment: Upvoted it, will wait with accepting it so other people are more likely to answer too.

Comment: Actually, your answer is correct, but for a different question. Because @Alagaros made a wrong assumption, his question is asked confusingly. Algaros, you say that "Ultear tells Gray there is no other way of beating Hades other then using Iced Shell." **after** their battle. That's incorrect. She said so before the battle because of the reasons Alchemist mentioned, but after, she only stated that Gray could not defeat Hades. Iced Shell was never mentioned again after their fight. She said that *despite him knowing iced shell was a lie, he could never defeat Hades* and she was correct.

Comment: So OP is basically asking whether Ultear knew about the heart and if she did know about the heart, why she didn't tell Gray about it. Iced Shell does not really have anything to do with this any more, because after Deliora, Gray would never ever use Iced Shell again any way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Ultear was under the impression that her mother had betrayed her and she wanted revenge on Gray. In reality, Ultear had too much magical power and Ur brought her to a place where she thought they would help decrease her magic power so she could live in peace but instead they tried to increase her magic power for Brain (from the Oracion Seis) but he was dissatisfied so the people who worked for Brain told Ur that Ultear died when Ultear escaped and ran away.
Ur eventually moved on and took in Gray and Lyon. Ultear had ventured all the way back home, excited to see her mother but got really mad when she say Ur with her students and she swore that she'd get revenge on them and get her mother back. Then, she found out Gray 'murdered' Ur and that she'd never get to confront her mother about the abandonment. Ultear (and Meredy) swore they'd kill him.
Gray learns that Ultear tried to decieve him after Ultear tried to kill Juvia and they battle. They both fall into the ocean (which has all of Ur's memories because when her iced shell melted her memories blended into the ocean.) and Ultear sees what really happened and her and Meredy apologize and leave, Ultear happy that her mother really did love her.